# Async searching with DbContext in a thread-safe way

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, async-await, entity-framework-core

I'm using EFCore 5 with an Azure SQL Server and a C#/WPF frontend. I'm using Fody to fire my PropertyChanged events.

I have a custom live search control with a TextBox containing the search string and a listbox displaying results.

TextBox.Text is bound to a string property, "SearchString". I subscribe to PropertyChanged and when this is fired, I call my repository classes to perform an async database search (actually in the query I have a few more .Where and .Include clauses, but have extracted the relevant parts):

```cs
result = await Context.Where(p => (p.Surname == surname)
    .OrderBy(p => p.Surname)
    .Take(maxResults / sString.Length).ToListAsync();

return result;
```

I then place the resultant list in to a property in the same class, which is bound to a ListBox.ItemsSource property. Until now, this has worked well (but slowly) synchronously - I am just switching over to async now.

My problem is that, despite "await"ing every asynchronous call to the database, if I type too quickly I get "A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed" on the DbContext class.

My best guess is that because my initial call to the DB Repository's search function is contained in an event, and that event is firing in the UI thread, it's "Overriding" the fact that I'm using await and causing a second query to run. I either need a way of stopping the first query, or a way of ensuring that the await is honoured.

Any suggestions for making this work well with ToListAsync(), but sill allowing the UI to feel responsive?

Comment: You should "debounce" the events for the user typing into the UI so you don't issue a query for every keystroke. Here's an article about it: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/jul/02/debouncing-and-throttling-dispatcher-events

Comment: Perhaps you could use a cancellation token.

Comment: The debounce system seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, @MartinCostello. I'm familiar with the concept through some work on microcontrollers but hadn't considered it on a Windows Desktop app!

Comment: Still, the problem is that your code allows multi-threaded acces to one context instance. You should always prevent that and not work around it. A debouncing mechanism doesn't guarantee that calls be serial.

Comment: @GertArnold Agreed that would be better. So any ideas how to do that? I guess actually doing the work on an explicitly created thread and then cancelling that thread would be one possibility. Any other possibilities you can see which still allow the use of async / await?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I subscribe to PropertyChanged and when this is fired, I call my repository classes to perform an async database search... despite "await"ing every asynchronous call to the database, if I type too quickly I get "A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed" on the DbContext class.
>
> My best guess is that because my initial call to the DB Repository's search function is contained in an event, and that event is firing in the UI thread, it's "Overriding" the fact that I'm using await and causing a second query to run. I either need a way of stopping the first query, or a way of ensuring that the await is honoured.

This is one of the [problems with `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void): it's not easy for calling code to know when the asynchronous method has completed. It's the `async void PropertyChanged` that is actually causing the problem.

> Any suggestions for making this work well with ToListAsync(), but sill allowing the UI to feel responsive?

First, I recommend debouncing as others have commented. That will reduce unnecessary db calls, although it won't fix this problem. For a proper fix, you should either have a pool of db contexts that your code allocates from (and returns to after the operation is complete), or just use a `SemaphoreSlim`. If you have one shared `SemaphoreSlim` (the same place where your existing `Context` is), and call `await semaphore.WaitAsync();` before the db operations and `semaphore.Release()` after the db operations, then that ensures one-at-a-time access:

```
await ContextMutex.WaitAsync();
try
{
  result = await Context.Where(p => (p.Surname == surname)
      .OrderBy(p => p.Surname)
      .Take(maxResults / sString.Length).ToListAsync();
}
finally
{
  ContextMutex.Release();
}
```

> I am just switching over to async now.

One nice feature of `SemaphoreSlim` is that it also works with synchronous code; you can have that code call `Wait` instead of `await WaitAsync`. You should apply the mutual exclusion to *all* accesses of `Context` to ensure correctness.

Comment: Another idea could be: Do the work if the semaphore can be acquired immediately, otherwise skip the work. `if (semaphore.Wait(0)) { try { /*...*/ } finally { semaphore.Release(); } }`

Comment: Thank you very much, @stephen-cleary! As I said, I'm only just starting out with async and I'm sure your suggested answer will help me with lots of my coding in the future.